# Z3, Hamiltonian Graph, Propositional Logic

Tags: graph, logic, z3

I'm hoping for suggestions on how to accomplish this:

Definition:
An undirected graph G is definied by a set V of vertices and a set E of edges where each edge is a subset of V of size two, i.e. an unordered pair {u, v} of vertices.  A cycle of length k in G is a sequenc v_1, ..., v_k of distinct vertices for which {v_1, v_2}, {v_2, v_3}, ..., {v_k-1, v_k}, {v_k, v_1} are all edges of G.  A Hamiltonian cycle in G is a cycle of length n = |V|, i.e. a chcle that passes through each vertex of the graph exactly once.  We call G Hamiltonian if it has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Problem:
Provide a propositional logic formulation of the following decision problem: given an undi-
rected graph G, is G Hamiltonian?  The formulation will be checked by Z3.

The input format will be:

```
4
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 0
1 3
```

where the first number represents the number of vertices and the remaining pairs are all edges in G.

The output should be: 0 1 2 3

Obviously the output will always be some permutation of the numbers 1, ..., n-1 where n = |V| but I don't see how to work with integers using only Proposition Logic.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Here's a solution that works for the given input.  If I could write a perl routine that would produce combinations (n Choose k) of edges then I could generalize this to any number of inputs:

```
(declare-const v0 Bool)
(declare-const v1 Bool)
(declare-const v2 Bool)
(declare-const v3 Bool)

(declare-const e1 Bool)
(declare-const e2 Bool)
(declare-const e3 Bool)
(declare-const e4 Bool)
(declare-const e5 Bool)

(assert (xor (and e1 e2 e3 e4) (and e1 e2 e3 e5) (and e1 e2 e4 e5) (and e1 e3 e4 e5) (and e2 e3 e4 e5)))

(assert (and v0 v1 v2 v3))

(assert (=> e1 (and v0 v1)))
(assert (=> e2 (and v1 v2)))
(assert (=> e3 (and v2 v3)))
(assert (=> e4 (and v3 v0)))
(assert (=> e5 (and v1 v3)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to let the SMT solver generate n numbers, say a1..an, and then assert all of the following:

- All these numbers are between 0 and n-1
- All the numbers are distinct
- The vertices a1 .. an form a cycle, i.e., check that there're edges between a1-a2, a2-a3, ..., a(n-1)-an and an-a1

That is, you just describe what a "hamiltonian cycle" is, and the SMT solver will find one if it does exist.

Now, the difficulty is how to express all this in SMTLib2 so that Z3 can parse it. Surely it can be done, but I'd advise using a higher level language that provides bindings to SMT solvers. Haskell and Scala are two such languages that you can script Z3 from, for instance.  That way, you just focus on the problem, and the host language will handle the translation behind the scenes for you. This requires some investment in learning the host language and the associated library, but it's well worth it in my opinion.

For instance, here's how you can solve this problem using Haskell and Z3: http://gist.github.com/1715097. The solution is a mere 7 lines of Haskell and you can use it to query any size graph you'd like. The solution takes advantage of the expressive power of Haskell and the SMT solver capabilities of Z3, presenting a clean interface.

Comment: The problem is that I am limited to propositional logic: and, or, not, implication.  I can't generate numbers.

Comment: If N is a constant (or at least if you know of an upper bound), then you can encode numbers using bit-strings, the usual binary expansion. For this problem you need comparisons, which can be done lexicographically. (This is essentially similar to "blasting", where the SMT solver turns bit-vector problems to SAT instances.) It wouldn't be pretty.

Comment: Regarding smt2 limitation: You can still use the Haskell library if you like, there's an API call to spit out the generated SMT-lib file that you can easily extract. Of course, generated code is never easy  to read, but it's much more likely to be more compact/correct than what you can write by hand.

Comment: Thanks.  But I need something much more low tech than this.  Basically I must write a Perl program that generates an smt2 file for Z3 that will return the edges that must be true when a Hamiltonian cycle exists.  I am limited to making assertions using Propositional Logic about the nodes and edges that are given as input.

Comment: I edited my post to show an ad hoc solution.  I need to be able to generalize it by writing a routine that takes combinations of edges (n Choose k).  But I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode edge relations by using boolean variables, for example use R-5-4 to denote if (5,4) in R.

Let E be your input edge relation.

Constrain a relation R to be a subset of E such that every vertex is connected to exactly two edges in R.

Now constrain a relation T to be the transitive closure of R.

If T is fully connected (all T-n1-n2 are true), R is a Hamilton cycle and (V,E) is a Hamilton graph.